# Deploying an ASP.NET Core Application with a database that is on a docker container

Tags: c#, json, docker, asp.net-core, deployment

I have built an ASP.NET Core Web App that has a database connected to a docker container that I would like to deploy to the web, making it accessible on any computer or mobile device using a url in the web browser.

Here is my appsettings.json code for the application:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "default": "Server=localhost,9999;Database=dbweb;User Id=sa; Password=Dbwebsql1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

The app as of now, only runs on localhost through this url: https://localhost:5001/, and its database is connected to a docker container named dbweb, that uses an image of mssql-server-linux:latest. Its docker port is 1433: and (MAC IP:Port) is 9999. The database runs locally, when I connect to it through Azure, the server name is "localhost,9999". Despite searching many sources online, and looking at similar questions on this topic, I am unable to find a clear solution for deploying my application. I would like to know if it is necessary to create a linode linux server or any remote server, connect to that server through ssh on terminal, and create a new docker container for my database on that server, as well as cloning the web app source code repo from github, to that remote server. Would it be better to create another vm server that hosts the docker container for sqlserver that my application will connect to, or is there a much better way? I was planning on using nginx to host my app on the remote vm server. BTW I'm on Mac OS. I am in search of an easier way to make the deployment process alot easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can achieve what you are trying to do.

Option a:

If you want full control over your server infrastructure (CPU,RAM,Memory), go with Azure's IaaS offering.
1. Create Azure Virtual machine with your desired OS
2. Install asp.net core web app hosting server, package your app, configure the hosting server and deploy the package
3. Install Docker
4. Create an image in AZ VM as you did in your local for MS sql server and run the container
5. Create a public IP to connect your VM through internet and configure DNS with FQDN.

Option b:

a) Azure's PaaS - App services to host your asp.net core web app [no need to maintain the OS/hosting server + you can choose between linux / Windows OS. Fully managed by Azure] and

b) PaaS - ACI (Azure Container Instances) for your database/db server [In ACI, no need to maintain OS or Docker. It is fully managed by Azure].

Also, ACI provides public IP and DNS labeled FQDN (fully qualified domain name) which you can use it in your web app's connection string as your db server name. You can use it to connect to your database through SSMS or Azure data studio from your local machine to check your data directly.

Note : ACI needs a docker image stored in a registry (DockerHub / Azure container registry / private registry)

Starting place with step by step good guidance are in

ACI:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6180/create-azure-container-instances-for-sql-server/

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6262/connect-to-and-monitor-sql-server-azure-container-instances-aci/

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopModernizing/wiki/05.-Deploying-the-Apps-to-ACI-(Azure-Container-Instances)

AppService:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/publish-app-svc?toc=%2Faspnet%2Fcore%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Faspnet%2Fcore%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsmac-2019&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.1

Once you setup the initial configuration, you can make the deployment (CI/CD) faster through Azure DevOps.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/devops/